# Handle Expired VOIP Push using apns-expiration

Tags: ios, swift, voip

This is linked with this question by me [Handle Expired VOIP push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57609832/handle-expired-voip-push)

I am trying to handle scenario already added in previous question. User1 calls but user2 is offline (no internet connection or unable to deliver voip push) ; when user2 back to online I don't want push to be delivered as it will open callkit interface which is compulsory from iOS 13

Now According to apple  [Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/sending_notification_requests_to_apns) there is **apns-expiration** key

> The date at which the notification is no longer valid. This value is a UNIX epoch expressed in seconds (UTC). If the value is nonzero, APNs stores the notification and tries to deliver it at least once, repeating the attempt as needed until the specified date. If the value is 0, APNs attempts to deliver the notification only once and doesn’t store it.

To test this I have turn off the internet and send voip push and after some seconds When I switch on the internet push actually received which should't be.

here is payload

```
aps =     {
    alert = "My first push notification!";
    "apns-expiration" = 0;
    badge = 0;
    "content-available" = 1;
    sound = default;
};
```

Could you please help me to deal this scenario

Thanks in advance

Comment: apns-expiration is a header sent to apple, it isn't directly part of the payload. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/sending_notification_requests_to_apns?language=objc

Comment: I too have this issue. did you find anything to fix this problem ?

Comment: @sarosar Nope, When I got the push, Anyway I show the call kit interface and on accept the call action I check is the receiver is still online to connect and perform an action accordingly.

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya How did you check that ? because I tried that too, once accept the call then I am calling one API to check whether receiver is still be online or not. it's woking fine while app is in foreground mode but when app goes background/terminated then API call not working :(. Did I miss anything here ?

Comment: @sarosar I am not using API , I am using the real time database or SOCKET

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? We are also receiving "expired" notifications even if we set apns-expiration header to 0

Comment: I am getting the same issue. Any solution? Documentation is not helpful

Comment: @MuhammadRaza I couldn't find anything to work , what I did is when I get push I show cal kit and on action  I reconfirm with the Server ( I have socket implemented)  and show user a message accordingly , If you find something better You are welcome to add answer I will Accept it :)

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya Problem is: user shouldn't get notification if user is off from internet. and connects after 1 mint. If we are setting expiry then notification is not reached to server and if we set 0 according to documentation notification will be sent if user is on the interview otherwise not, but its sending.

Comment: @MuhammadRaza Try to send this on header